# netCDF does not display properly in QGIS 1.8

Tags: qgis, netcdf

I have a netCDF file of fire emissions on a regular grid of 12 km by 12 km grid cells with 200 east-west grid cells by 161 north-south grid cells centered on the continental United States.  The map projection is Lambert Conformal.  I am using QGIS v1.8.  When I open the raster it displays as a very, very tiny raster located in mid-northern reaches of the State of Kansas.  Can someone tell me what blunder I am performing?

Comment: Sounds like a projection error. What exactly is the projection of your grid?

Comment: There are lots of lcc projections defined for Northern America. I wonder how the data can cover the whole US with that. Apart from choosing the right one, there are also some projections in feet instead of metres.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps units? The grid seems to be 12km*(200x161)= 2400km x 1932km, while the continental US is closer to 5000km x 2500km.

If "very, very tiny" is on the order of 2.400km x 1.932km, it may be a km vs. m units problem as well.